# Mapping bearing and speed of ocean currents

Tags: r, r-raster

I have two matrices of bearing and speed data for ocean currents

```
bearings <- matrix(data = c(170.0833, 175.6863, 182.3538, 180.3335, 170.8965, 
                            178.3276, 182.3693, 187.2196, 182.3533, 168.3498, 
                            189.1664, 187.6813, 187.0393, 180.2259, 166.8412, 
                            193.4223, 188.5367, 182.4128, 175.2626, 167.3058, 
                            192.2930, 185.5073, 175.0302, 168.6284, 167.8392),
                   ncol = 5, nrow = 5, byrow = F)

speed <- matrix(data = c(0.1389173, 0.1585099, 0.1796583, 0.2021887, 0.2117295,
                         0.1196745, 0.1463118, 0.1637266, 0.1730471, 0.1804999, 
                         0.1309982, 0.1546123, 0.1593298, 0.1517513, 0.1550037, 
                         0.1621728, 0.1694083, 0.1606560, 0.1459710, 0.1457233,
                         0.1659898, 0.1535861, 0.1396885, 0.1294339, 0.1337756),
                 ncol = 5, nrow = 5, byrow = F)
```

I wanted to graph the direction of the current bearings with arrows, while the magnitude/speed of the current is represented by the length of the arrow, a bit something like these maps:

[image]
*Wind stress figure taken from Shankar et al. 2002*

I know the package [`oce`](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Could_you_suggest_a_software_to_plot_current_speed_and_direction_patterns) may be able to do something like that, but it specifically works with different types of oceanographic data rather than matrices/data frames that I'm using.

Anyone happen to know how to do that? I have gotten as far as making them into raster objects using the `raster()` function from the `raster` library:

```
library(raster)
bearing.rst <- raster(bearings,
                      xmn = 66,
                      xmx = 67.3333,
                      ymn = 10.6667,
                      ymx = 12)
speed.rst <- raster(speed,
                    xmn = 66,
                    xmx = 67.3333,
                    ymn = 10.6667,
                    ymx = 12)
```

Ideally I'd do this with base R graphics, or with a package that plays nice with base R graphics (e.g. not `ggplot2` or `lattice`).

Graph from:

Shankar, D., Vinayachandra, P.N., & Unnikrishnan, A.S. (2002). The monsoon currents in the north Indian Ocean. *Progress in Oceanography, 52:* 62-120. doi: [10.1016/S0079-6611(02)00024-1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0079661102000241)

Comment: `geom_segment` can do that using ggplot2. http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I cam across that, but wasn't sure how I could fit the `speed` matrix into that like they did with `delta_long` and `delta_lat`. Also, is there anything in base R graphics that do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with base R:

```
plot(bearing.rst)  # your base map, I use this because I didn't have it
```

Get your  starting coordinates:

```
arr.coor <- rasterToPoints(bearing.rst)
arr.coor <- cbind(arr.coor[,-3], bearing=c(t(bearings)), speed=c(t(speed)))
```

Calculate your finishing coordinates with trigonometric functions:

```
x1 <- arr.coor[,1] + arr.coor[,4] * cos(arr.coor[,3]*pi/180)
y1 <- arr.coor[,2] + arr.coor[,4] * sin(arr.coor[,3]*pi/180)
arr.coor <- cbind(arr.coor, x1, y1)
```

Plot your arrows:

```
arrows(arr.coor[,1],arr.coor[,2],arr.coor[,5],arr.coor[,6])
```

[image]

I guess the same principal could work with ggplot2. The idea is to get a table with all your arrows origin and end.

Answer (score 3):

With `ggplot`

```
bearings <- c(170.0833, 175.6863, 182.3538, 180.3335, 170.8965, 
                            178.3276, 182.3693, 187.2196, 182.3533, 168.3498, 
                            189.1664, 187.6813, 187.0393, 180.2259, 166.8412, 
                            193.4223, 188.5367, 182.4128, 175.2626, 167.3058, 
                            192.2930, 185.5073, 175.0302, 168.6284, 167.8392)


speed <- c(0.1389173, 0.1585099, 0.1796583, 0.2021887, 0.2117295,
                         0.1196745, 0.1463118, 0.1637266, 0.1730471, 0.1804999, 
                         0.1309982, 0.1546123, 0.1593298, 0.1517513, 0.1550037, 
                         0.1621728, 0.1694083, 0.1606560, 0.1459710, 0.1457233,
                         0.1659898, 0.1535861, 0.1396885, 0.1294339, 0.1337756)



df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:5,5), 
                 y = rep(1:5, each = 5),
                 bearings = bearings,
                 speed = speed)

df$dx <- sin((df$bearings)/360*pi*2)*df$speed
df$dy <- cos((df$bearings)/360*pi*2)*df$speed

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x + dx, yend = y + dy),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1,"cm"))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: plot]